# Writing an effective for-loop in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to write a for-loop so that the code below can generate outputs for `m=0,1`? Right now, I am using `m=0` and `m=1` manually. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np

T2=[[0, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11],[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11]]

X=np.array([np.array([4.17551036e+02, 3.53856161e+02, 2.82754301e+02, 1.34119055e+02,
              6.34573886e+01, 2.08344718e+02, 1.00000000e-24])               ,
       np.array([4.17551036e+02, 3.32821605e+02, 2.94983702e+02, 2.78809292e+02,
              1.26991664e+02, 1.36026510e+02, 8.31512525e+01, 2.07329562e+02,
              1.00000000e-24])                                               ],
      dtype=object)

C1=0.0

index=0

m=0/1

for j in range(T2[m][-1]):
    if(j!=T2[m][index]):
        X[m] = np.insert(X[m], j, C1, axis=None)  
    else:
        index+=1
print([X[m]])
```

The current output is

```
m=0:

[array([4.17551036e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 3.53856161e+02,
       0.00000000e+00, 2.82754301e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       1.34119055e+02, 6.34573886e+01, 2.08344718e+02, 1.00000000e-24])]

m=1:

[array([4.17551036e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 3.32821605e+02, 2.94983702e+02,
       0.00000000e+00, 2.78809292e+02, 1.26991664e+02, 0.00000000e+00,
       1.36026510e+02, 8.31512525e+01, 2.07329562e+02, 1.00000000e-24])]
```

The expected output is

```
array([array([4.17551036e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 3.53856161e+02,
              0.00000000e+00, 2.82754301e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
              1.34119055e+02, 6.34573886e+01, 2.08344718e+02, 1.00000000e-24]),
       array([4.17551036e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 3.32821605e+02, 2.94983702e+02,
              0.00000000e+00, 2.78809292e+02, 1.26991664e+02, 0.00000000e+00,
              1.36026510e+02, 8.31512525e+01, 2.07329562e+02, 1.00000000e-24])                         ],dtype=object)
```

Comment: with the current code, what is the final `X`?  What's wrong with that?

Comment: The current code simply does not work. `m` is a float variable so there is an error. Please fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Add an outer `for` loop:

```
for m in [0,1]:
    for j in range(T2[m][-1]):
        if(j!=T2[m][index]):
            X[m] = np.insert(X[m], j, C1, axis=None)  
        else:
            index+=1
```

Comment: There is an error: ```in <module>
    if(j!=T2[m][index]):

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list```.

Comment: `if(j!=m[index]):`

Comment: ```in <module>
    if(j!=m[index]):

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: The output is not the same as mentioned in the expected output.

Comment: You asked how to run the for loop for m = 0 and m = 1 without manually changing it - I’m not clear what you mean about the output?

Comment: I mean the output I am getting by using the for-loop you suggested is not the same as the expected output I mentioned in my post.

Comment: Do you mean the `print([X[m]])`? Because that only prints the last item in the list, you’d need to do `print(X)` to print the whole list. If not then you need to make your question clearer.